# NSTrackingArea in moving NSWindow causes rapid toggle

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I am making a Xamarin.Forms for MacOS application. I have an NSTrackingArea within the main NSWindow, which triggers the window to resize when the mouse enters / exits.

```
public class MyWindow : NSWindow {
    public event EventHandler MouseEnter;
    public event EventHandler MouseLeave;

    public override void MouseEntered(NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        base.MouseEntered(theEvent);
        MouseEntered?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public override void MouseExited(NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        base.MouseExited(theEvent);
        MouseLeave?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the user can rapidly move the mouse over and out of the window causing a chain of window resizes, and if the mouse is positioned correctly then the window will resize back and forth indefinitely.

**What I've Tried**

- Toggling the NSWindow's IgnoresMouseEvents, but it causes more issues than it solves.
- Removing and adding MouseEnter and MouseLeave listeners after each is invoked

I'm guessing that most of the issue is that the resizing is done on a different thread which allows the resizes to accumulate.

Comment: how are you resizing the windows? Maybe add an 'IsResising' mechanism.

Comment: There is a relationship that allows a Xamarin.Forms class to call the MyWindow SetFrame (not directly, but essentially). I resolved it with your flag suggestion which is a simple enough solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a CanToggle property for the NSWindow class extension. MouseEnter and MouseLeave check this flag; if CanToggle is false, then nothing is executed. Outside classes can set the CanToggle property when appropriate.